# One sprinkler system zone has low pressure problems

Tags: sprinkler-system

I have a sprinkler system with low to no pressure on Zone 3

Zone 1 2 4 5 all have good pressure

I had a guy come in and put in egress windows in my Basement

He broke one of the sprinkler main lines to the Heads

On one side of my House  He union-ed the line together and he showed me

My line do not seem plugged and solenoid seems to work OK Is it possible the he may have pulled a joint apart to the One side of the house

Zone 3 is both sides of my house and I know the pvc pipe is at least 4 foot deep

PLEASE advise me

I cannot find any water coming from the ground

Thank you

Keith

Comment: If debris got in the line is possible a mesh filter in each head is plugged.  It’s the same concept as cleaning the aerator on your kitchen or bath sink.  You can usually take nozzles off at the head to find out if your getting full pressure if not, then the next stop if the valve.

Comment: Another option is to dig up the repair and unhook it since it is a union. turn the solenoid valve on for a moment and see if water floods the repair area. If so then you either have plugged heads or the solenoid won't energize completely to open the valve.